# Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - error in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

At first, I'm checking if `self.statisticsArray.count == 0` then I create a new record, else I'm updating the exist value. When I create a new object, all okay, but when I'm trying to update the exist one, it crashes with the next error:

```
Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first
```

But I do it all in one `.write` block, why it rises such error? I read that if I use `.write()`, then I do not need to close the transaction. Can anyone describe me why it crashes?

```
if self.statisticsArray.count == 0 {
     self.statistics.summary = 250

     try! self.realm.write({
         self.realm.add(self.statistics)
         self.realm.add(record)
     })
 } else {
     if day == self.statisticsArray.last?.date {
         try! self.realm.write({
             self.realm.objects(Statistics).last?.summary += 250
             self.realm.add(record)
         })
     } else {
        try! self.realm.write({
             self.statistics.summary = (self.statisticsArray.last?.summary)! + 250
             self.realm.add(self.statistics)
             self.realm.add(record)
        })
     }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`self.statistics.summary = 250` needs to be within the write transaction. It should look like this:

```
if self.statisticsArray.count == 0 {

     try! self.realm.write({
         self.statistics.summary = 250
         self.realm.add(self.statistics)
         self.realm.add(record)
     })
}
```

Comment: no, it's not a solution. It still crashes. And why it shouldn't? `self.statistics.mlSummary = 250` is just a class variable.

Comment: If the `statistics` property is a Realm object that has been added to a Realm, then editing any of its properties needs to occur in a write transaction. Just because it is a property of `self` doesn't change this.

Comment: @AdamFish putting `self.statistics.summary = 250` into the `write` block does not help. What do you advice me?

Comment: you should turn on exception breakpoints so that the debugger can pause execution on the exception and you can figure out what line of code the error is happening in. The code you pasted doesn't appear to have any other issues as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

I also had such a problem, and I decided like this.

```
let model = RealmModel()
model.realm?.beginWrite()
model.property = someValue
do {
    try model.realm?.commitWrite()
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer

Comment: Is it self-explained?